# Keep postgres docker container in azure pipeline job running

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, docker, azure-pipelines

I'm rather new to Azure and currently playing around with the pipelines. My goal is to run a postgres alpine docker container in the background, so I can perform tests through my python backend.

This is my pipeline config

```yaml
trigger:
  - main
pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  POSTGRE_CONNECTION_STRING: postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:passw0rd@localhost/postgres
resources:
  containers:
    - container: postgres
      image: postgres:13.6-alpine
      trigger: true
      env:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: passw0rd
      ports:
        - 1433:1433
      options: --name postgres
stages:
  - stage: QA
    jobs:
      - job: test
        services:
          postgres: postgres
        steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: $(PYTHON_VERSION)
          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: '"$(PYTHON_VERSION)" | "$(Agent.OS)" | requirements.txt'
              path: $(PYTHON_VENV)
              cacheHitVar: 'PYTHON_CACHE_RESTORED'
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: Wait for db to start
            inputs:
              script: |
                sleep 5
          - script: |
              python -m venv .venv
            displayName: create virtual environment
            condition: eq(variables.PYTHON_CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')
          - script: |
              source .venv/bin/activate
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install -r requirements.txt
            displayName: pip install
            condition: eq(variables.PYTHON_CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')
          - script: |
              source .venv/bin/activate
              python -m pytest --junitxml=test-results.xml --cov=app --cov-report=xml tests
            displayName: run pytest
          - task: PublishTestResults@2
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
              testResultsFiles: 'test-results.xml'
              testRunTitle: 'Publish FastAPI test results'
          - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
            inputs:
              codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
              summaryFileLocation: 'coverage.xml'
```

But the pipeline always fails at the step "Initialize Containers", giving this error:
`Error response from daemon: Container <containerID> is not running` as if it was just shutting down because there is nothing to do. Which seems right, but I don't know how to keep it running until my tests are done, the backend just runs pytest against the database. I also tried adding that resource as container using the `container` property, but then the pipeline crashes at the same step, saying that the container was just running less than a second.

I'm thankful for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspicious that your container is not stopping because of "there is nothing to do", the postgres image is configured in a way to act as a service. Your container is probably stopping because of an error.

I'm sure there is something to improve: you have to add the `PGPORT` env var to your container and set to `1433` because that port is not the default port for the postgres docker image, so opening that port on your container like you are doing with `ports` is not doing too much in this case.

Also, your `trigger: true` property would mean that you are expecting updates on the official DockerHub repository for postgres and in case of a new image release, run your pipeline. I think that does not makes too much sense, you should remove it, just in case, although this is marginal problem from the perspective of your question.

Comment: You are right about the port, it was the one I used previously for an mssql database. This actually fixed it and I hate myself for not realizing this earlier.

Comment: No worries. I just got lucky, that's it :D